# How to make a UserControl float over rest of xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, window

English is not my primary language, edits are more than welcome.

I've decided to make my own, specialized title bar in my wpf application. So far, everything was going pretty well. Until I had to make something appear under the title bar (at the press of a button for say) but OVER the rest of the window content.

I made a custom Style for every Window that I will want to have my titlebar that goes like this:

```
<Style x:Key="EditFormStyle" TargetType="Window">
    <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                <DockPanel>
                    <c:TitleBar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                    <c:ValidationPannel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
                    <ContentPresenter DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So the content of the Window will be under my TitleBar. This goes perfectly well. Then I wanted to add the ValidationPannel that would display some stuff on the press of a button for Visibility ON/OFF. Pretty usual feature there. The problem is that I want the ValidationPannel to be under the titleBar (which it is) but **over** the rest of the content of the window. As you can see, I tried to use a ZIndex with no success. It keep pushing the content under it.

Is there a way to make the UserControl *float* over the content, hidding it until I say it to be invisible again?

Thanks in advance.

-->again, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand what should be over what but if you want to put 2, or more, controls on top of each other then you can use `Grid`.

> Child elements of a Grid are drawn in the order in which they appear in markup or code. As a consequence, layered order (also known as z-order) can be achieved when elements share the same coordinates.

So lets say you want to put `ValidationPannel` on top of `DockPanel` with `TitleBar` and `ContentPresenter`

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <c:TitleBar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </DockPanel>
        <c:ValidationPannel/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

also you don't have to set `DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"` on `ContentPresenter` as by default, it will be ignored and last child of `DockPanel` will fill all remaining space:

> If you set the [LastChildFill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to true, which is the default setting, the last child element of a DockPanel always fills the remaining space, regardless of any other dock value that you set on the last child element.

Comment: This will have the validation panel over both the title bar and the content.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I wrote _"Not sure I understand what should be over what"_

Comment: Both your two answers solved my problem by updating my understanding of the container concept in wpf. Thank you to both of you. I upvoted you two but because dkozl came in first I'll make his answer my approved one.

Answer (score 1):

DockPanel will always have this behavior, you should use something else for your content presenter container (like Canvas or Grid) that doesn't automatically adjust the other controls when something new is added to the layout. Effectively, you need to use a container that supports absolute positioning.

Something like this should do what you want. Note that I haven't included any position logic, this is just the container hierarchy.

```
<DockPanel>
    <c:TitleBar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter/>
        <c:ValidationPane/>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

If you wanted to be really clever, you could set up the grid to have two rows (one the height of your validation panel, the other * height), put the Validation panel in the first one, and have the Content Presenter span both. That way, your validation is always at the top (over the content), and the ContentPresenter fills the way it would if it were just the last element in a DockPanel.